# HttpResponse response = client.execute(request); Working in avd browser but not in application

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am using the following code to send some information using get method to the servlet running on xampp server  on my laptop, AVD is also running on same laptop . I can access the servlet using browser in AVD but from the activity I created.

```
public void get() throws Exception{
            new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    TextView tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.statusView);
                    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
                    try{
                    URI address=new URI("http://10.0.2.2:8080/HelloWorld?FirstName=saligrma&LastName=verma");
                    request.setURI(address);
                    tv.setText("URI build \n");
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        //koi bat ni na;
                        tv.setText("Not able to build the URI \n");
                    }
                   // setProxyIfNecessay(context, request);
                    try {
                        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                       // tv.setText("StatusCode: " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() );
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        tv.setText("some error occured ");
                    }
                }
            }.start();
        }
```

my servlet code is here

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException

  {  java.sql.Connection con = null;

         String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDataBase";
         String user="root";
         String password="root";
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            String fn= request.getParameter("FirstName");
            String ln= request.getParameter("LastName");
        try {Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            Statement st = (Statement) con.createStatement();
                st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO firstName VALUES('"+fn+"')");

            con.close();
            }

         catch (Exception ex) {
          out.println("<p>  Error Error Occured </p>");

           } 
  }
```

Comment: what is error? provide logs also

Answer (score 0):

That happened to me some time ago. Try using your computer's IP (you can get it using ifconfig in linux/mac and ipconfig /all in windows command line) instead of `http://10.0.2.2:8080`. Accessing localhost from apps in AVD is somewhat problematic.